# VS 2013 Query Designer greyed out

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I believe I am following the instructions at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms171960.aspx but whatever I try, the Query Designer toolbar remains greyed out and 'Query Designer' does not appear in the main menu. Am I missing something?
(VS2013 version 12.0.21005.1 REL connecting to a SQL 2008 R2 Express db)

Answer (score 1):

[Have posted similar problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982318/visual-studio-2013-sql-query-and-view-designer-not-appearing) - Solved on this thread.

Create two connections in VS Server Explorer.

1) Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient):

Use this for editing tables, and for the connection string in the software.

2) Microsoft SQL Server + .NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB:

Use this for visual queries.

Everything is VS, Publish options don't give 'file in use'.

On a completely unrelated Twilight Zone moment - you posted the same question, on the same day, on the same forum, and both our names are Peter G!

Comment: This is the only solution that works for me so far to have both the capability to see table definitions and sizes, but also still use the query designer.  It doesn't seem like it should be _necessary_ to have two iterations of the same connection to get the same functionality I used to get with one, but...