# How to view new query option for this database?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 community.I've created a local database.The connection is successfull but i want to create a new query for it.When i click right click i cannot see the option new query.What can i do?[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know in **Visual Studio 2013** the *query designer* and *database diagram* features are no longer available from the **Server Explorer**. The only was is to access it from the **SQL Server Management Studio**.

But, I think this might solve your problem [Visual Studio 2013 SQL Query and View Designer not appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982318/visual-studio-2013-sql-query-and-view-designer-not-appearing)